# Set user profile fields that are not visible on registration form

Tags: users, forms

Very new to Drupal, first of all. I'm working on a custom module for user registration (we're still in Drupal 6) that I'd like to do a few things:

1. Geocode the user-supplied zipcode to get a city/state (uses US as default country as we're a regional news organization, but lets users pick another one if desired). *This part works nicely.*
2. If this is successful, add those values to the respective user profile and save them (these are hidden fields on the profile module settings). **This part does not work**
3. If this is not successful, add an error to the zipcode field. *This works nicely as well.*

I've been assuming that I could use `form_set_value` on a validation hook, but I realized that this may not work because the fields aren't visible. So I tried making one visible, but it still didn't work, so I'm at a loss.

Here's what I have (leaving out the geocode stuff, as it works well):

```
function module_name_form_user_register_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'module_name_user_register_validate';
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') .'/module_name.js');
}

function module_name_registration_user_register_validate($form, &$form_state) {

  $zip = $form_state['values']['profile_zip'];
  $country = $form_state['values']['profile_country'];
  $country = countries_api_iso2_from_name($country, COUNTRIES_API_FORMAT_ISO2); // uses the countries_api module to get country code

  if (!isset($country) || $country == 0) {
    $country = 'US';
  }
  $postal_check = get_city_state($zip, $country); // geocode the zip/country combo as json

  $location = json_decode($postal_check);
  $city = $location->postalcodes[0]->placeName;
  $state = $location->postalcodes[0]->adminName1;

  if ($city == '' || $state == '') {
    form_set_error('profile_zip', 'You entered an invalid zip code. Please try again. If you are not in the United States, make sure you chose your country correctly.' );
  }

  form_set_value($form['profile_city'], $city, $form_state);
  form_set_value($form['profile_state'], $state, $form_state);
  form_set_value($form['profile_country'], $country, $form_state);

}
```

Any ideas?